# $row value lost when going to other page using controller

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Whenever I'm going to the designated page using the controller, $row values are lost.

The code below shows how I get to the new page.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td><a href='?article=del&".$row["id"]."'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></a></i></td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";
    }
```

Normally, in my complete table, all the data is shown, including the ID and the names in the db etc. But when I get to the new page, the $row value is lost. For example the del page would be this:

```
<?php
function del() {
    print $row;
}
```

I would get this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp64\www\SMS2\article\del.php on line 3

Instead, the url DOES show the $row["id"] for example:

http://localhost/SMS2/index.php?article=del&15

In this case I clicked on the row which had the 'id' value of 15.

So basically, the $row value does get loaded in the url, which is 15, but is lost in the actual page when I try to print it.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't see the rest of your code, your URL is missing the definition of what 15 is. You need to have a variable in the URL. For example:

```
http://localhost/SMS2/index.php?article=del&id=15
```

Instead of

```
http://localhost/SMS2/index.php?article=del&15
```

Then in your code you would use something like $_GET['id'] to pull the value of 15 out of the URL.

Comment: Nope, then I'd get undefined index: id

Comment: Well, if you're not expecting the ID then you would get an undefined message but you should really only be expecting it when preforming that function. The way you have it setup right now, it will never work the way you're wanting it to. Unless you're concatenating the article value and exploding based on the ampersand. Without more code it's difficult to assist.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<a href='?article=del&".$row["id"]."'>
```

into:

```
<a href='?article=del&id=".$row["id"]."'>
```

and on the other page:

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id']; 

print $id;
?>
```